# Google Places API works in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-places-api

I use the Google Places API and when I change address it works perfectly in Chrome but doesn't always work in Mozilla Firefox.

I use jQuery, Bootstrap 4 and JS and Symfony 4 for the backend.

```js
function onPlaceChangedEditUser() {
  console.log('1');

  var place = this.getPlace();
  $('.postal_code').val('');

  for (var i in place.address_components) {
    var component = place.address_components[i];
    for (var j in component.types) {
      var type_element = $('.' + component.types[j]);
      if (component.types[j] == "country") {
        $('#country').find('option').attr('selected', false);
        $('#country').find('option[data-country="' + component.short_name + '"]').attr('selected', true);
        $('#country_iso').val(component.short_name);
        $('#country').change();
        $('.country-short').val(component.short_name);

        if ($('.country').length) {
          $.ajax({
            url: Routing.generate("front.dashboardbabysitter.find.language"),
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
              "cache-control": "no-cache"
            },
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            data: {
              'isoCountry': component.short_name
            },
            success: function(json) {
              if (!json.hasError) {
                $('.country option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
                $('.country option[value=' + json.idLanguage + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
                $('.country').val(json.idLanguage);
              }
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
              if (textStatus !== 'abort') {
                var error = "TECHNICAL ERROR: unable to send login informations \n\nDetails:\nError thrown: " + XMLHttpRequest + "\n" + 'Text status: ' + textStatus;
                $.growl.error({
                  message: error
                });
                return false;
              }
            },
            complete: function() {}
          });
        }

        if (jQuery.inArray(component.short_name, mp_country_prefix)) {
          var phone_number = '+' + mp_country_prefix[component.short_name];
          var flag_class = (component.short_name).toLowerCase();

          $('#flag').removeClass().addClass('flag position-absolute ' + flag_class);

          $('#phone').val(phone_number);
        } else {
          console.log('there is no iso');
        }
      }

      if (type_element) {
        type_element.val(component.long_name);
      }

      if ($("#latitude").length) {
        $("#latitude").val(place.geometry.location.lat());
        $("#longitude").val(place.geometry.location.lng());
      }

      if ($(".latitude").length) {
        $(".latitude").val(place.geometry.location.lat());
        $(".longitude").val(place.geometry.location.lng());
      }

      if ($('#address1').length) {
        $('#address1').val($('.street_number').val() + ' ' + $('.route').val())
      }

      if ($('#edit_babysitter_personal_info_address_address1').length) {
        $('#edit_babysitter_personal_info_address_address1').val($('.street_number').val() + ' ' + $('.route').val())
      }

      if ($('#parent_personal_info_address_address1').length) {
        $('#parent_personal_info_address_address1').val($('.street_number').val() + ' ' + $('.route').val())
      }
    }
  }
}

function initializeAutocomplete(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  if (element) {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element, {
      types: ['geocode'],
      language: _mpop.current_lang
    });

    if (id == "parent_personal_info_fullAddress" || id == "edit_babysitter_personal_info_fullAddress" ||
      id == "address_bb" || id == "home_address") {
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', onPlaceChangedEditUser);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the console for errors in Firefox

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan any error display in console .. console is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addEventListener` instead of `addListener`

Reference - [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Identify the browser and apply the event accordingly.